# Logging on Spark

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-spark

I'm using Spark to distribute a job which is currently not distributed. Many classes generate useful logging (log4j), and these classes are not supposed to be Spark-specific (they implement filtering operations and stuff, so they should be used as is).

However, their code is executed on the slaves, so I don't get this logging back to the master. Is there a clever way, with no Spark-related code in these classes, and changes as minor as possible, to do this ?

PS : as the tags show it, I'm working with the Java API.

Comment: In what distributed mode do you intend to run your job (standalone, yarn, mesos)?

Comment: For now, I run in standalone mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your code you may consider configuring log4j to deliver the log messages to a central location.
You can choose e.g. [FlumeAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender%20FlumeAppender), [JMSAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JMSQueueAppender%20JMSAppender) [JDBCAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender%20JDBCAppender)...

If you don't like any of these you can implement your own appender.

Comment: Yeah, I tried writing a custom appender using Spark accumulators, however it is kind of annoying because I have to append it at multiple places of my code. Indeed, the way I understand it is that the accumulators are serialized, so if I want to add an appender I have to do it in the code of my tasks before each stage, otherwise I am not appending the right instance of the accumulator